# How to put HTML code as string in HTML page?

Tags: html

I am sending HTML news letters and composing them run-time. I need to put HTML code as string in the HTML news letter. Since the HTML code I need to place as a string is also html it executes in the browser but I dont want this, I want to display that code itself. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why -1??? Who is this god on the planet earth who knows everything and votes -1 for humans who knows less than them.........

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the HTML in `<code>` or `<pre>` tags

and make sure you use an [HTML entity encoder](http://htmlentities.net/) on the code first so that it will display `<` and `>` properly.

Comment: For added fun, if you can execute javascript, you can use something like SyntaxHighlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to make the code all purty-like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the `<` and `>` as well as other html special characters.  Many languages have libraries that do this such as php's `htmlspecialchars` and ruby's `h()`, but it seems like you're just writing the HTML out.

```
<pre class="htmlcode">&lt;html&gt;</pre>
```

The above would display `<html>`.